# Using (Collections of) Tuples as Class Properties in a Public API

Tags: c#, api

I have a parameter object that represents a single match in a competition, and one of its properties needs to contain that match's game scores for both players. For example, in a match determined by a best of three games, the scores are 3 to 1, 1 to 2, and 10 to 0. I'm tempted to use tuples:

```
public class MatchParameters
{
    public IEnumerable<(int Player1Score, int Player2Score)> Scores { get; set; }
}
```

After some research on the matter, I've seen plenty of warnings against requiring the use of tuples in the public-facing side of an API. Do I introduce a `MatchScore` class/struct and use that as the type argument for `Scores`? I just really like the convenience of being able to do something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public SomeReturnType Bar()
    {
        var p = new MatchParameters()
        {
            Scores = new[] { (3, 1), (1, 2), (10, 0) }
        };
        // More stuff...
    }
}
```

Though I guess I can see how a dedicated type would provide additional clarity for users of the API. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard advice about giving things good names I think still applies here. You'll read the code an order of magnitude (or two) more than you write the code, so err towards making that less error-prone. And while your example code looks nice, *consuming* tuples will be quite a bit less legible. Particularly for a public API, I'd recommend a formal DTO so you can better control serialization and versioning.

Answer (score 3):

Dedicated types provide names, and naming things is very important in programming as you only write the code once, but you’ll read it dozens, possibly hundreds, of times.  Good names can save you from serious mistakes.

If you can write this API for the latest version of C#, you can use records.

```cs
public record MatchScore(int PlayerOneScore, int PlayerTwoScore);
```

You can’t get much smaller than that, and whenever you read it, you’ll know immediately what it is and what it represents.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have asked for convenience, here is a code example that defines a DTO (a C# `struct`) for the pair of scores, while still allowing easy and non-verbose array initialization.

The main insight is that a DTO can implement **an implicit conversion operator *given* a C# 7.0 Tuple parameter**. There might be unintended quirks for doing so. Nevertheless, it seems to give you the convenience (during array initialization) which you asked for.

*(For brevity, all class names have been reduced to their initials. This is done for display reason; do not mimic this aspect in any practical software projects.)*

```
struct S1S2
{ 
    public int S1 { get; }
    public int S2 { get; }
    public S1S2((int S1, int S2) s1s2)
    {
        S1 = s1s2.S1;
        S2 = s1s2.S2;
    }
    public static implicit operator S1S2((int S1, int S2) s1s2)
    {
        return new S1S2(s1s2);
    }
}

class MP
{ 
    public IEnumerable<S1S2> Scores { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mp = new MP()
        { 
            Scores = new S1S2[] { (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1) }
        };
    }
}
```